# Getting req.user undefined in passportjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have configured passportJS with node express app but when I make login/register request then in that case req.user is undefined any idea what is wrong am I missing something in configuring passport js? I have used express-session and mongoDB store for storing sessions

passport-config.js:

```
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const User = require("./Models/userSchema");

passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: "email",
      passwordField: "password",
    },
    async (email, password, done) => {
      try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });
        // Username/email does NOT exist
        console.log("user in config", user);
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, {
            message: "Username/email not registered",
          });
        }
        // Email exist and now we need to verify the password
        const isMatch = await user.isValidPassword(password);
        return isMatch
          ? done(null, user)
          : done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password bro" });
      } catch (error) {
        done(error);
      }
    }
  )
);

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async function (id, done) {
  const user = await User.findById(id);
  done(null, user);
});
```

server.js file: https://pastebin.com/NfpvXSFf (see line 39)

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
async (req, res) => {
{email, password, done} = req.body;
```

(you need a body-parser for that)